# @Bean as Inner Class not working in SpringTesting (No default constructor found)

Tags: spring, unit-testing, inner-classes

I'm trying to write test with bean classes as innerClasses.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={SpringContextConfigurationClassesExample.BeanA.class})
public class SpringContextConfigurationClassesExample {
    @Autowired
    private SpringContextConfigurationClassesExample.BeanA beanA;

    @Test
    public void verifyBeans() {
        assertNotNull(beanA);
    }

    @Component
    public class BeanA {
        public BeanA(){}
    }
}
```

But have an exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate
>   [com.javarticles.spring.SpringContextConfigurationClassesExample$BeanA]:
>   No default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.javarticles.spring.SpringContextConfigurationClassesExample$BeanA.()

Is it possible and how to write this test ?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but this logically will never work. You spin up Spring context to load all the beans and components, then you run the test - in which you create relevant bean. Dependencies cannot be met.

Comment: Carefully read the exception -- BeanA: No default constructor found. Paste this class to the question, please

Comment: Andriy, BaenA is a inner class of SpringContextConfigurationClassesExample class.

Comment: `BeanA` is not a configuration, so remove it in the context ConfigurationConfiguration annotation.

Comment: What I was missing was the use of `classes` attribute of the `@ContextConfiguration`.
⚠️ But be aware, that it won't only resolve that classes components and its inner classes components, but also all the ones from the given class package (if we follow its documentation).
-- And as said below and given in many other Stackoverflow threads, in most cases, your inner class should be declared *static*.

Answer (score 0):

Use Static Nested Class instead Member Inner Class.

```
@Component
    static public class BeanA {
        public BeanA(){}
    }
```